# PHP Email validator (form) from brackets

Tags: php, html, validation, email

I need help with the first $headers line.
I need the from to look like this:

```
name <email>
```

actually

```
$field_name <$field_email>
```

It should show from email in email client

```
Personname <person@emailaddress.com
```

How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];

$mail_to = 'from@email.com';
$subject = 'Enquiry from Website, From: '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'Enquiry submitted to business, via website contact form.';
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Telephone Number: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '$field_name' <'$field_email'>'"\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email.;

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
include 'contactendd.php';

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'thanks.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'thanksfailed.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: `$headers = 'From: '$field_name' <'$field_email'>'"\n";` - you forgot `.` to concatenate

Answer (score 0):

This line is the right idea:

```
$headers = 'From: '$field_name' <'$field_email'>'"\n";
```

but it should read

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $field_name . ' <' . $field_email . '>\n';
```

Just missed the periods to concatenate

Answer (score 0):

Headers should be separated by CRLF `"\r\n"` -- not just `\n`.

Comment: Can you further explain as to why not just a simple one liner.